# Can you use SQLCMD to generate scripts from 2012 to run in 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I need to take some databases from 2012 back to 2008 and I have done most using the generate scripts method (select 2008 as one of the options and schema and data). When I hit a large database, I get an error about Insufficient Memory to continue the execution of the program. Is there a way to use SQLCMD in 2012 and still pass in the flags so that it will generate a script to be run on SQL 2008? Or any other option or known size limit for using SSMS to generate scripts for large databases? 
Thanks for any help,
Mike

Comment: It may be possible to import the DB into SSDT ("new" VS Database Project template) and then elect to deploy to a different SQL Server version

Comment: Now that I offered a solution, I realize I may not fully understand the question. Are you trying to migrate the data from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Yes. I have a server with 2012 and some databases on it that I need to move to a 2008 instance. Generate Scripts works since you can give it the options to include schema and data and make the script run for a specific version of SQL. It's just a problem with large cases throwing the insufficient memory error when trying to generate the script.

Comment: This is probably long since closed, but it sounds to me like your database just has too much data to convert it all into a text script (given the programming of SSMS). The script will likely be larger than the raw data because it includes all of the code overhead. What if you just script the structure, but then use a backup to file and restore from file approach to load the data? I'm not sure that would work between versions though...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite easily using the SQL Server Import Export Wizard. If you have special constraints setup on the tables, you may want to create those tables first. The tool is fairly quick and gives step-by-step status updates.